# what does ^ mean in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

What do the `'^.^'` and `'^'` strings mean in this AngularJS code?

```
if (isFilterState()) {
  $state.go('^.^.' + report.subtype, {id: report.id});
} else {
  $state.go('^.' + report.subtype, {id: report.id});
}
```

Comment: What is `$state` exactly? Probably this syntax is related specifically to that module/service?

Comment: This seems to be using the AngularUI Router framework.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stateproviderstatestatename-stateconfig

String Absolute State Name or Relative State Path

The name of the state that will be transitioned to or a relative state path. If the path starts with ^ or . then it is relative, otherwise it is absolute.

Some examples:

```
$state.go('contact.detail') will go to the 'contact.detail' state
$state.go('^') will go to a parent state.
$state.go('^.sibling') will go to a sibling state.
$state.go('.child.grandchild') will go to a grandchild state.
```

Comment: @Sunil Think of it as a traversal method. `^` goes up 1 state, `.name` goes down one state. `^.^.` goes up two states. `^.foo` goes up one state and then goes back down one state to `foo` which is either the same state or a sibling state of the current state.

Comment: Or, maybe an easier to follow example: If the current state is `/products/camera/gopro/`, `^.^.` will travers to `/products`, `^.cannon` will travers to `/products/camera/cannon`, and `.buynow` will travers to `/products/camera/gopro/buynow`